# How do I calculate the transfer function of a filter in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have to do some exercises in a Digital Signal Processing course and I have some problems.

I have a given file (signal.wav name the signal `x(n)` ) with some noise added and iIam asked to find some information from it. The noise added is `η(n) = sin8000πn`. So the signal I am processing is `s(n) = x(n) + η(n)`

In order to remove the noise, I apply a low-pass butterworth filter with `order = 2` and cutoff frequency = 2000hz.

I want to find the transfer function `H(s)` from the filter and the `H(z)` function. Well I know that I have to apply bilinear transformation but iIdont know how to do it with MATLAB.

Can anyone help me solve this?

Here is my code

```
[y, fs, nbits] = wavread('signal.wav');

% Playing the file
disp('-> Playing at the original sample rate...');
sound(y, fs);

fprintf('------------------------------------------\n');
% Sampling frequency
fprintf('-> Sample frequency is:      %f.\n', fs);

% Print the min and max values of the audio data.
fprintf('-> The maximum data value is %f.\n', max(y));
fprintf('-> The minimum data value is %f.\n', min(y));
fprintf('------------------------------------------\n');

order = 2;
sampling_freq = fs;
cut_off_freq = 2000;

[butter_a, butter_b] = butter(order,cut_off_freq/(sampling_freq/2));
%[butter_a, butter_b] = butter(order,cut_off_freq/(sampling_freq));

subplot(211), plot(y);
subplot(212), plot(filter(butter_a,butter_b,y));

sound(filter(butter_a,butter_b,y),fs);
```

Comment: ITYM *transfer function* (not "transport function") ? You might also be better off asking this in http://dsp.stackexchange.com since it's more DSP-related than programming-related.

Comment: Sorry i tried to translate from my native language. I meant transfer function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`freqs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/freqs.html) to calculate the frequency response/transfer function of your analog filter (i.e., `H(s)`). So in this case, something like:

```
freqs(butter_b,butter_a,200);
```

will plot the frequency and phase response for the filter at 200 frequency points. You can also provide a vector of points where it should be calculated (see the linked doc).

---

For the transfer function of the digital filter (i.e., `H(z)`), use [`freqz`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/ref/freqz.html). So your syntax would be something like:

```
freqz(butter_b,butter_a,[],fs)
```

which will again plot the frequency and phase responses as before. Again, make sure you read the linked documentation to understand and use it correctly.

Comment: Thanks that's what i needed. I only changed 200 to 148864 cause it is the actual number of samples in the signal. Now i have another problem. The plot gives me frequencies x 10^4 so i see the cutoff at 2  x 10^4 = 20000hz instead of 2000hz.

Comment: ah, I see what the problem is. The output for `butter` in your code should be collected as `[b,a]` i.e., numerator coefficients first. You've reversed the order. Flip that and try this, you should get the cutoff at 2k Hz.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know the frequency of the unwanted component of the signal you need only to estimate the phase and amplitude and then subtract the added noise component from your signal in the time domain to get the solution.

There are many ways of estimating the phase and amplitude of a sine. I suggest you try the Goertzel algorithm for that.

Comment: As i said before i apply a low-pass butterworth filter to remove the noise. The exercise says so.